Cramer family of distribution
Show that one parameter Cauchy distribution with pdf,

f(x,theta)=(1/pi)*(1/(1+(x-theta)^2)), x and theta are real valued

Belongs to Cramer family, Prove all 5 conditions.

Please use latex

What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?
